# How to sort List<List<String>> by first element of every list?

Tags: java, sorting, java-stream

How can I sort List of Lists by first element of every list? I have list like this:

```
[angel, angle, galen, glean, lange]
[abel, able, bale, bela, elba]
[elan, lane, lean, lena, neal]
[caret, carte, cater, crate, trace]
[evil, levi, live, veil, vile]
[alger, glare, lager, large, regal]
```

And I want to

```
[abel, able, bale, bela, elba]
[alger, glare, lager, large, regal]
[angel, angle, galen, glean, lange]
[caret, carte, cater, crate, trace]
[elan, lane, lean, lena, neal]
[evil, levi, live, veil, vile]
```

How can I do this using Stream?

Here is my code:

```
List<List<String>> lis = new ArrayList();

stream.collect(Collectors.groupingBy(s -> getAnagramKey(s)))
    .values().stream()
    .sorted(Collections.reverseOrder(Comparator.comparingInt(List::size)))
    .limit(15)
    .forEach(e -> {
    lis.add(e);
 });

final int maxSize = lis.stream().map(List::size).max(Integer::compare).orElse(0);

lis.stream()
    .filter(e -> e.size() == maxSize)
    .forEach(System.out::println
);
```

Comment: What is the problem with your Code?

Comment: Since you already know `collect`, you can get rid of the `forEach` with `add` in the first stream pipeline. You have not mentioned, what is the relevance of `maxSize` in this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could just call `Comparator.comparing` for this:

```
List<List<String>> sortedList = 
    lis.stream().sorted(Comparator.comparing(x -> x.get(0)))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

You don't need streams if you just want to sort the list in place. `List.sort` will do the job:

```
lis.sort(Comparator.comparing(x -> x.get(0)));
```

Also, don't use raw types. Write `ArrayList<>`, not `ArrayList`:

```
List<List<String>> lis = new ArrayList<>();
```

Comment: On the lines of performing the `get(0)`, it might just be safe enough to add a `.filter(l -> !l.isEmpty())` before the sorting operation.